# Can 3D rotation be inferred from its effect on directional observations?

Tags: 3d, rotations

I am thinking about a camera-based gyro that can infer the 3D orientation of an observation platform, by locking onto two (or more) known directional beacons.

Assume there is a reference coordinate axis system (with an origin and defined axis-directions for x-y and z.)  Now, assume a mobile platform (mobile in 3D such as a spaceship) having its own local x-y-z axes.  A full-spherical camera system on the platform can sense the direction of any observed directional beacon (a visible point like a very-distant galaxy, so far removed that it's apparent direction does not change observed over the entire nav-space.  Let there be a lookup table of reference directions for these beacons (directions in reference coordinates).  You can think of each beacon having a unique 3D direction vector d =  [ x y z ], or if you prefer, equivalent azimuth-elevation angle-pair [ phi theta ].

Can you solve this problem?  Using as few as two recognized beacons, you acquire (measure) the directions of these beacons in your local axis system:

d1 ,  d2   (measured directions with platform's 3D orientation superimposed)

You lookup from the reference galaxy chart the known reference directions for these two beacons:

d1_ref ,  d2_ref

Can you suggest a math formula or algorithm that crunches these 4 pieces of data into the 3D orientation of your observational platform (in relation to reference axes)?  I.e., can you turn your spherical hi-res camera into a gyroscope through software that combines your local directional observations to their known directions in reference coordinates?

An acceptable output would be a 3x3 rotational matrix, equivalent quaternion, or equivalent (roll, pitch, yaw) angles.

Comment: ...yes, and it's not that hard. Suppose the directions (both 'known' and observed) are given as unit vectors. Then a rotation that maps $\vec D_{o0}$ onto $\vec D_{k0}$ is just a rotation around the unit vector in the direction $\vec r_0 = \vec D_{o0}\times \vec D_{k0}$ by an amount proportional to the length of that cross product; apply this to the other observed vector $\vec D_{o1}$ to get $\vec D'_{o1}$, and then just find the rotation about $\vec D_{k0}$ that carries $\vec D'_{o1}$ to $\vec D_{k1}$, and compose.

Comment: That's simple.  Is there a name for this approach?

Comment: Not specifically that I know of; this specific problem isn't very common, but the broad approach of converging into the final answer on a sort of 'layer-by-layer' basis shows up all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems of this type can be solved by remembering that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. Using this fact, you can easily construct a pair of matrices that map between the reference and camera coordinate systems, respectively, and some common intermediate coordinate system. You then compose one with the inverse of the other to get the direct transformation.

In this case, you can use the coordinate system defined by the two measured reference objects as the common intermediate. For the third coordinate axis, take the cross product of the two vectors, which is guaranteed to be linearly independent of them (assuming that the two beacon vectors are linearly independent, i.e., not scalar multiples of each other). If $\mathbf d_1$ and $\mathbf d_2$ are the coordinates of the beacons in the reference frame and $\mathbf d_1'$, $\mathbf d_2'$ the coordinates measured by the camera, then the matrix that maps from the intermediate coordinate system to the reference coordinate system is simply: $$M_{\text{ref}}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf d_1 & \mathbf d_2 & \mathbf d_1\times\mathbf d_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ and from the intermediate coordinate system to the camera’s: $$M_{\text{cam}}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf d_1' & \mathbf d_2' & \mathbf d_1'\times\mathbf d_2' \end{bmatrix}.$$ We want to know what the the camera’s coordinate axes are in the reference frame, i.e., the images of the unit basis vectors under the camera-to-reference-frame mapping. Per the observation made at the start of this answer, these are the columns of $M_{\text{ref}}M_{\text{cam}}^{-1}$. This matrix maps from one orthonormal coordinate system to another, and, as is easily verified, $\det(M_{\text{ref}}M_{\text{cam}}^{-1})=1$, so it is indeed a rotation. Note that you don’t need unit vectors for this, nor does the order in which you take them matter, as long as it’s consistent between the two matrices.

This is a theoretical result that assumes perfect data, but will work well with high-resolution measurements. In practice, to compensate for noise and other inaccuracies in the measurements, you’d more likely instead use observed positions of many more reference objects and compute a best-fit rotation from them.

Comment: That's nice, amd.  The only improvement would be to construct the two matrices  as fully orthonormal by not using d2 directly, but this way:

      Mref =  [  d1     (d1xd2)xd1     d1xd2  ]  (insures 3 orthogonal axes)

      Mcam = [  d1'   (d1'xd2')xd1'   d1'xd2' ]  

Yes, the angular width of the d1-d2 wedge must be equal to the angular width of d1'-d2'.   And the wedges cannot be very close to 0 or 180 degrees in width.   But, other than that, it looks like a robust algorithm...I think we've captured all the edge cases.

Comment: @pbierre I see no compelling reason to make the two intermediate matrices orthogonal (which the ones you suggest are not, BTW: their columns aren’t unit vectors). That’s extra work that introduces the potential of more numerical instability and ends up getting canceled out when you multiply them together. An advantage to doing so is that you can avoid a matrix inversion and use the transpose instead, but the inversion isn’t particularly expensive for a $3\times3$ matrix and might be cheaper than the square roots needed to construct orthogonal matrices.

Comment: I agree with your thinking, amd.   Either approach to generating the "intermediate" matrices works.  I think the reason I chose to use orthonormal matrices is just that I'm more familiar with the way they work, and, yes, they can be inverted by just transposing row and column indices.

Can you give an example of how using the orthonormal 3x3 would contribute to numerical instability?  Is there a test case that would reveal the problem?

Comment: @pbierre To orthogonalize the matrices, you’ll have to compute a square root for every column, which loses a lot of precision. How much that matters will depend on how good your inputs are. GIGO.

Comment: I only use 64-bit double math, so generally arithmetic error from square roots (or multiples and adds) is kept quite manageable.  There is BigDecimal representation if more than 15 decimal digits of accuracy are needed by an app.  

The applied math problem I threw out could apply to future interstellar navigation.  The mechanical gyros on the Hubble Telescope failed at about the 15-year mark, and those were able to be replaced at great expense ($1B).   On an interstellar mission, you'd like an all solid state gyro system (no moving parts).

Comment: A final (I hope) note: All of the $M_{\text{ref}}$ matrices can, of course, be precomputed.